# Send GET in Ajax call and PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, get

I want to POST data from form. It works fine.
In the other functionality i want to get data from database.

I don't know where is mistake. I suspect that AJAX call is fine.

My PHP code:

```
<?php

$uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
$minor = $_POST['minor'];
$mayor = $_POST['mayor'];
$lokalizacja = $_POST['lokalizacja'];

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else{
    echo "Polaczono";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO beacons (uuid, major, minor, lokalizacja)
VALUES ('$uuid', '$minor', '$mayor', '$lokalizacja')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Dane dodano prawidłowo";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sqlget = "SELECT uuid, major, minor, lokalizacja FROM beacons";
$result = $conn->query($sqlget);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode(array("value" => "UUID: " . $row["uuid"]));
    }
} else {
    echo "Brak rekordów w bazie";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

AJAX call:

```
$('#admin').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if( ($("input[name=uuid]").val().length) > 40 || ($("input[name=minor]").val().length) > 5 || ($("input[name=mayor]").val().length) > 5 || ($("input[name=lokalizacja]").val().length) > 20){
        $(".error-pola").show();
    } else{
        $.post('administrator-connect.php', $(this).serialize() )
        .done(function(){
            $(".success-wyslanie").show();
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $(".error-wyslanie").show();
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",                                    
        url: 'administrator-connect.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("fsdfsd"+ data);
        },

        error: function(){
            alert("not");
        }
    });
});
```

---

I am using:

```
echo json_encode(array("UUID" => $row["uuid"]));
```

and in ajax:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "administrator-get.php", function(data) {
  var jsonx = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  $( "#data-listing" ).html(jsonx);
});
```

But I get response:

{"UUID":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"}

How to get only string ?

Comment: The `GET` request seems to be sent to the same PHP file, the PHP file expects `$_POST['uuid'];` values. Also to make an `insert` to the database is more correct to be done via `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: You are also outputting invalid json by outputting multiple json strings in your `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo json_encode(array("value" => "UUID: " . $row["uuid"])); }` loop

Answer (score 0):

If you write this

```
dataType: 'json',
```

It expect for JSON value not string be sure to return only JSON.

You returns string value not JSON.

With like this code

```
 echo "Polaczono";
```

Any echo would be the return value for ajax

At last you should return only one value like this.

```
    echo json_encode($result);//an array result
```

You can check by string return.  By removing `dataType`